# Magento 2: Overriding addtocart.phtml for Configurable Products

Tags: magento2, product, module

I've create a module and overriden addtocart.phtml to replace the 'Add to Cart' button with 'Preorder' when the Preorder attribute is set to 'Yes'.

This works well on simple products, but I cannot override the button on configurable products (products with options).

Template hints show the following on the add to cart button for simple products:

`/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/app/code/Max/Preorder/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

Configurable shows:
`/var/www/html/magento/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

I'm not really sure what is going on here, I can see the path is slightly different but I have no luck when trying to override that file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: I assume you're aware that the path is different because the simple products have the path to your module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this -

First clear your `var/cache` folder using command

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/cache/view_preprocessed/*`.

Now check template path using path hint for both type products.

In default magento `addtocart` button is rendered from template file for both `simple` and `configurable` products

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

You need to check `catalog_product_view.xml` layout file where template file is defined for both type of products.

In this xml, this code is used for `simple` products-

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

and this code is used for `configurable` products template file --

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
```

as you can see for both type of products same file `addtocart.phtml` is being used.

So check this xml file for your theme, might be different template file are set there for both type of products

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect. It turns out I had forgotten to specify configurable products in catalog_product_view.xml. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your welcome @Max :)